# Onclick js function disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, social-networking

Ok here's the problem: I have a sidebar where all the friends are and their online status. If you click on a friend, they appear at the footer and a chat box appears at the bottom of the screen.

On the top of the chat box there are 2 buttons that have images inside. One a minimize, the other a close button. When the minimize button is clicked, the chat box is removed but they stay in the footer. If the close button is clicked the chat box is removed and they are removed from the footer.

This all works fine and dandy but when I click the minimize button, `<button onclick='minimize()'>...</button>` and reclick the friend, the close button's `onclick` is empty and doesn't work... Also I tried using jQuery's `.click` function but it didn't do anything.
Alright, i got another computer...here's my jquery code:

```
function minimizefcc(){
   var current_friend = $("#fcc_container header span").text(); //get current chat window username
   $("li.fcc_li"+current_friend+"_username").attr('data-activeconnection', 'false');
   $("li.friend_li."+current_friend+"_username").attr('data-activeconnection', 'false');
   $("#fcc_container").remove();//get rid of chat box(fcc_container = friend chat    container)
}

function closefcc(){
   var current_friend = $("#fcc_container header span").text(); //get current chat window username
   $("li.fcc_li"+current_friend+"_username").attr('data-activeconnection', 'false');
   $("li.friend_li."+current_friend+"_username").attr('data-activeconnection', 'false');
   $("#fcc_container").remove();//get rid of chat box(fcc_container = friend chat    container)
   $("li.fcc_li."+current_friend+"_username").remove();
   $("li.friend_li."+current_friend+"_username").attr('data-fcopen', 'false');
}

//heres the main code

$(document).ready(function(){
   var friendli = $("li.friend_li");
   var footer = $("#footer");
   var fccli = $(".fcc_li");
   friendli.click(function(){
      var username  = $(this).attr("data-fcusername");
      var open = $(this).attr('data-fcopen');
      var active = $(this).attr('data-activeconnection');
      if(open === 'false' && active === 'false'){
         //friend isn't in footer and isn't in chat box
         $(this).attr('data-fcopen', 'true');
         $(this).attr('data-activeconnection', 'true');
         $("#footer #fcc_ul").append("<li class='fcc_li "+username+"_username' data-   activeconnection='true' data-fcopen='true' data-fcusername='"+username+"'>"+username+"<img   src='you dont need the source' title='status' class='status_img "+username+"_status'/></div>");
         minimizefcc();
         $("body").append("<div id='fcc_container'><header id='fcc_header'><span>"+username+"</span>"+
"<button id='fcc_minimizeButton' onclick='minimizefcc()'><img src='you dont need source...' title='minimize'/></button>"+
"<section id='fcc_messageContainer'></section><textarea id='fcc_input'></textarea></div>");
      }

      if(open === 'true'&& active === 'false'){
         //friend is in footer but not in chatbox
         $(this).attr('data-activeconnection', 'true')
         minimizefcc();
         $("body").append("<div id='fcc_container'><header id='fcc_header'>" +
         "<button id='fcc_minimizeButton' onclick='minimizefcc()'><img src='you dont need source...' title='minimize'/></button>"+
         "<section id='fcc_messageContainer'></section><textarea id='fcc_input'></textarea></div>"):
         $("li.fcc_li."+username+"_username").attr('data-activeconnection', true');
   });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you post some code to show what you have tried? That will make it easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Error is certainly line 314, there's a missing parenthesis.

Comment: You really need to post more of you jQuery code.

Comment: Problem is computer I'm on doesn't have Internet...

Comment: Should I take a picture?

Comment: Sorry there are a few mistakes but just ignore them I had to write it in..no copy and paste

Comment: We cannot ignore mistakes, otherwise how do we know which mistake is "the one" you need us to fix?

Comment: The thing is I'm using a good text editor so it would have Cauthen any dumb mistakes, but ill try to fix them anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i would like to apoligize as it was a very dumb mistake...in the second if where i add the button i forgot to add the onclick='closefcc()', just being a dumbass, mybad.

Comment: No worries, most of us make dumb mistakes from time to time.